# Access Config Parameter without Container

Tags: symfony, dependency-injection

What is the recommended way of accessing the global config parameters? I know you should inject just what you need, but the whole point of global parameters (in most cases) is to set application defaults. And I WANT the defaults to be universal, even if I allow passing in overrides on a function by function basis.

### THE PROBLEM

I have a `ViewVersion` entity with a `ViewVersionRepository` where I have common functions for interacting with that entity.

One of these functions requires that I know a certain parameter from the config.yml (e.g. `cms.save.newVersionSeconds` so I know when it's been more than 30 minutes since the last save and I should create a new version record). The entity repository is not container aware though, so I can't access the config with the normal method:

```
$myParam = $container->getParameter('my.custom.param');
```

**Inject From Controller**

If I call this function from a controller, no problem I can get the config in the controller and inject the parameter into the repo function.

```
$myParam = $container->getParameter('my.custom.param');
$viewVersionRepository->myFunction($myParam)
```

**Global Service**

Or I can configure the the repo as a service:

```
gutensite_cms.view_version_repository:
    class: Gutensite\CmsBundle\Entity\View\ViewVersionRepository
    factory_service: 'doctrine.orm.cms_entity_manager'
    factory_method: 'getRepository'
    calls:
        - [setLimit, ['%cms.limit.list.admin%']]
        - [setNewVersionSeconds, ['%cms.save.newVersionSeconds%']]
```

And then set the parameter with setter injection via the `calls` arguments in the `services.yml`. And then load the service:

```
$viewVersionRepository = $this->container->get('gutensite_cms.view_version_repository');
```

**Complication**

However... I have a situation where I'm loading this viewVersionRepository within a doctrine onFlush event listener. And there I don't have access to the container (natively), so I can't actually load the global service. I have access to the entity though so I was loading the repo via:

```
$repo = $em->getRepository('GutensiteCmsBundle:View\ViewVersion);
```

But when you load it that way, it's not loaded as a service so the setter injection doesn't happen...

### ONE SOLUTION

So I could pass the container into the global onFlush event listener service, so that I can load the ViewVersionRepository as a service (and for that matter have the container to the load the parameters if I wanted).

gutensite_cms.listener.is_versionable:
        class: Gutensite\CmsBundle\EventListener\IsVersionableListener
        #only pass in the services we need
        arguments: [ "@gutensite_cms.entity_helper" ]
        calls:
            - [setContainer, ["@service_container"]]
        tags:
            - { name: doctrine.event_listener, event: onFlush }

But I'm told **over and over and over again* to **ONLY** inject the parameters you need. And to avoid injecting the entire container. This onFlush event is really quite dynamic, loading the corresponding onFlush event in any entity's repository that has an onFlush method. So in one entity repository the custom function may need access to one parameter, but in another entity repository the may need access another. So I can't really pass in just one parameter.

And it seems to me that passing the entire container makes your application far more coupled than if you were to just used the vilified $GLOBALS or CONSTANT for your global default config. So surely there is a better way to avoid **both** these evils. Not to mention you should NEVER inject the container into an entity repository.

**So isn't there some way to access the global config parameters WITHOUT injecting the entire blessed container?** Does no one EVER need global config parameters in an entity repository? Sure I could move this function to another service... but why? This is one of the basic functions of this entity, e.g. it determines if it should be versioned or not.

Comment: Why not just inject the parameter into your `onFlush` and then call your repository method using the injected parameter as an argument? That way the repository method is quite loose and you won't be stuck to using a (semi) hardcoded argument.

Comment: @Qoop this entity onFlush needs one parameter, but other onFlush methods for other entities, may need different parameters. So it seems like it's not very flexible to hard code the parameter I need. I can hack that, but I guess I'm wondering what the bigger recommended solution is for platform design. The point of having a config file is to store default configuration for your app. So it seems really strange that you have to inject that configuration in everywhere. Yes, maybe inject the ability to overwrite the default, but the default should be easily accessible if not specified?

Comment: It depends what you mean by flexible. If you are only injecting a single parameter then this listener could be moved to a different project (or framework, or maybe no framework at all) easily as you will only need to make sure that you have that have that single parameter set in the construct. If you mean that you don't need to think as much beforehand then injecting the container would be easier but you are then tied down to a listener that will work with only a specific framework (or at least a DI container that uses that same sort of interface)

Comment: Correct. In my case, I'm building a CMS and the code is specifically for this project and this project only. It's debilitating to have to always consider that your code must be able to be used in any conceivable way, even if you have no plans to ever do so. So given that reality, is there a recommended way to access the config parameters globally, without injecting the entire container (which itself is a worse dependency). Thanks!

Comment: I guess you could create some kind of parameters holder object that you inject all of your parameters to and inject that into what ever you want to use those parameters in. That way you could give it an interface (and type hint) so ensuring you were at least getting the right object. To be honest I really don't see what the issue with writing out the actual parameters that you want on each service, that way you can see from the YAML markup what is going into each service rather than having to dig through. It's really up to you though to be fair.

Comment: Thanks. The parameters object is an interesting idea I've read others suggest to. I'm not sure what you mean by "writing out the actual parameters that you want on each service". Are you saying, just inject the parameters you need into each service as arguments or calls? In some cases the service is generic, so that doesn't work unless I make it specific to only one use case. Maybe that's okay, but I am still hesitant about how much to rely on services, I dislike having code for functionality spread out over 5 places if I can help it.